# Fastest solution to get rows of group with largest group average

Tags: r, performance, grouping

#### Reprex

Suppose I have a numeric matrix `m`:

```r
m <- as.matrix(iris[-5])
#      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# [1,]          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
# [2,]          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
# [3,]          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
# ...
```

And a vector `groups` that group the rows of `m`:

```r
groups <- as.character(iris$Species)
# [1] "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" ...
```

##### Question

What is the *fastest* way to return rows the rows of `m` for the group with the largest average value across all columns? If possible, I would also like to keep track of the original row numbers.

#### Expected Output

In this example, the group `"virginica"` has the largest average value:

```r
sapply(split(m, groups), mean)
#     setosa versicolor  virginica 
#     2.5355     3.5730     4.2850
```

So the expected output would be:

```r
m[groups == "virginica", ]
#       Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#  [1,]          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5
#  [2,]          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9
#  [3,]          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1
# ...
```

As mentioned the row numbers reset after sub-setting, I would be interested in a solution that also keeps track of the original row numbers (in this case those would be `101-150`).

---

Most SO questions that I read tend to center on taking rows with the largest value(s) *within* each group rather than returning the rows of the group with the largest average.

So one potential solution (that does not keep track of row numbers) would be:

```r
m[groups == names(which.max(sapply(split(m, groups), mean))),]
```

But I am curious if there are faster options (I am guessing the fastest option may be `data.table`). Please include a benchmark. In my actual problem I have a list of several thousand matrices and each of matrix has several thousand rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tweaking @Maël's answer for an additional speedup:

```
library(Rfast)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  "fmean + rowMeans" = m[groups == names(which.max(rowMeans(fmean(m, groups)))),],
  "fmean + rowSums" = m[groups == names(which.max(fmean(rowSums(m), groups))),],
  "fmean + rowsums" = m[groups == names(which.max(fmean(rowsums(m), groups))),],
  check = "identical",
  unit = "relative",
  times = 1e3
)
#> Unit: relative
#>              expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
#>  fmean + rowMeans 1.203125 1.205882 1.101343 1.200000 1.234899 0.9703661  1000
#>   fmean + rowSums 1.171875 1.176471 1.112008 1.171429 1.194631 0.9947705  1000
#>   fmean + rowsums 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.0000000  1000
```

The speedup becomes more pronounced with larger matrices:

```
m <- matrix(runif(1e6), 1e3, 1e3)
groups <- sample(LETTERS, 1e3, 1)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  "fmean + rowMeans" = m[groups == names(which.max(rowMeans(fmean(m, groups)))),],
  "fmean + rowSums" = m[groups == names(which.max(fmean(rowSums(m), groups))),],
  "fmean + rowsums" = m[groups == names(which.max(fmean(rowsums(m), groups))),],
  check = "identical",
  unit = "relative"
)
#> Unit: relative
#>              expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
#>  fmean + rowMeans 7.206646 6.533759 5.260140 6.170580 5.935219 0.8081945   100
#>   fmean + rowSums 6.070651 5.497177 4.481413 5.150618 4.902984 1.5396386   100
#>   fmean + rowsums 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.0000000   100
```

Answer (score 2):

This base R solution is simple, and it shouldn't be slow. `rowMeans` is coded in C and is a fast function.
Only the first 6 rows are printed.

```r
vec <- as.matrix(iris[-5]) |> rowMeans()
s <- tapply(vec, iris$Species, mean) |> which.max() |> names()

iris[iris$Species == s, ] |> head()
#>     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
#> 101          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5 virginica
#> 102          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
#> 103          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1 virginica
#> 104          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8 virginica
#> 105          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2 virginica
#> 106          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

The code above as one pipe followed by the final subsetting.

```r
s <- iris[-5] |>
  as.matrix() |> 
  rowMeans() |>
  tapply(iris$Species, mean) |> 
  which.max() |> 
  names()

iris[iris$Species == s, ] |> head()
#>     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
#> 101          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5 virginica
#> 102          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
#> 103          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1 virginica
#> 104          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8 virginica
#> 105          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2 virginica
#> 106          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here are two possibilities using `collapse::fmean`. The execution with `fmean` and `rowMeans` instead of `mean` and `split` is 3x times faster than the benchmark.

```r
library(collapse)
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  base = m[groups == names(which.max(sapply(split(m, groups), mean))), ],
  fmean = m[groups == names(which.max(fmean(split(m, groups)))), ],
  "fmean + rowMeans" = m[groups == names(which.max(rowMeans(fmean(m, groups)))),]
)

# Unit: microseconds
#              expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
#              base 217.801 226.9510 260.34502 237.6000 259.8510 698.400   100
#             fmean 155.301 165.0010 192.98291 173.3515 197.0010 444.701   100
#  fmean + rowMeans  61.500  70.2505  83.35604  78.8510  87.4515 187.101   100
```